# Updating matlab version to 2013b on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: matlab

I have matlab 2012b installed and working on my ubuntu 12.04 box, I just downloaded, installed, and activated the 2013b version using the GUI defaults under root priviledges, but when I start matlab from the command line, the old 2012b version pops up.

How do I change matlab root from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012b to /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b, and delete the 2012b version, so when I type matlab in the terminal command line R2013B pops up?

(I see that in the /usr/local/bin there is a matlab file and mex file, the latter referring to the 2012b version, but it is read only).

Comment: Isn't removing the old MATLAB a option?

Answer (score 1):

There is no uninstaller for MATLAB on UNIX or Linux. To remove MATLAB you simply need to delete the MATLAB installation following the instructions below:

1. If you are running a license manager for MATLAB, shut down the license manager using the 'lmdown' script located in MATLAB's etc directory. If this folder does not exist, you are not running the FlexNet license manager. For example:

   ```
   sudo /usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b/etc/lmdown
   ```

   You should also remove any license manager files in the /var/tmp directory. These files should begin with 'lm_TMW', ex:

   ```
   sudo rm /var/tmp/lm_TMW*
   ```
2. Remove the entire root MATLAB directory using the 'rm -rf' command, ex:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/MATLAB/R2010b
   ```
3. Remove any symlinks to MATLAB binaries on the path, ex:

   ```
   sudo rm /usr/local/bin/matlab /usr/local/bin/mcc /usr/local/bin/mex /usr/local/bin/mbuild
   ```

adjust values for your version.